# Use .htaccess to Block Yandex, Baidu, and MJ12bot

Tags: .htaccess

I am so tired of Yandex, Baidu, and MJ12bot eating all my bandwidth. None of them even care about the useless robots.txt file.

I would also like to block any user-agent with the word "spider" in it.

I have been using the following code in my .htaccess file to look at the user-agent string and block them that way but it seems they still get through. Is this code correct? Is there a better way?

```
BrowserMatchNoCase "baidu" bots
BrowserMatchNoCase "yandex" bots
BrowserMatchNoCase "spider" bots
BrowserMatchNoCase "mj12bot" bots

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bots
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To block user agents, you can use :

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (yandex|baidu|foobar) not-allowed=1

 Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=not-allowed
```

Comment: So this will search for each of those strings regardless of text case and regardless of if it is YandexMobileBot or BaiduSpider or part of any larger string?

Comment: Yes, this will match any of the listed user agents in a case insenstive manner.

Comment: @Pathfinder Sorry ,there was a slight typo in my answer. I changed **user_agent** to **user-agent** (correct variable)

Comment: sweet, I will test your answer. Thank you.